# Exception in thread. I am not able to execute this program

Tags: java

I'm just a beginner in Java. Please help in executing this simple program. It throws an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 at sum.main(sum.java:7)
```

The Program

```
class sum {
    public static void main(String args[]){
       int a,b,c;

       a=Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
       b=Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
       c=a+b;

       System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you call the program? With an IDE or a console?

Comment: @Blobonat Console

Comment: Then have a look at the answer from Davide Lorenzo MARINO

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass at least two parameters to your java program.

For example:

```
java sum 10 45
```

If you start the program from an ide (eclipse or IntelliJ or others), for default no parameters is passed to run the program. You need to edit the run configuration manually adding them. I use IntelliJ, in IntelliJ this is done setting a field named **Program Arguments**. In eclipse is something similar.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked.

Comment: @Jijin Maybe you have a look at [Command-Line Arguments](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html) to understand what `args[]` actually is.

Comment: @Jijin you are wellcome. If the answer is correct you can flag it as correct with the green flag.